# Python 3: subprocess.run('mv') leaves target open

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a script that uses a really simple file based IPC to communicate with another program. I write a tmp file with the new content and `mv` it onto the IPC file to keep stuff atomar (the other program listens of rename events).

But now comes the catch: This works like 2 or 3 times but then the exchange is stuck.

```
time.sleep(10)
# check lsof => target file not opened
subprocess.run(
    "mv /tmp/tempfile /tmp/target",
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
    universal_newlines=True,
    shell=True,
)
# check lsof => target file STILL open
time.sleep(10)
```

`/tmp/tempfile` will get prepared for every write

The first run results in:

```
$ lsof /tmp/target
COMMAND  PID        USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF  NODE NAME
python  1714      <user>   3u   REG   0,18      302 10058 /tmp/target
```

which leave it open until I terminate the main python program. Consecutive runs change the content as expected, the inode and file descriptor but its still open what I would not expect from a `mv`.

The file is finally gets closed when the python program featuring these lines above is getting closed.

**EDIT:**

Found the bug: mishandeling the `tempfile.mkstemp()`. See: https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.mkstemp

I created the tempfile like so:

```
_fd, temp_file_path = tempfile.mkstemp()
```

where I discarded the filedescriptor `_fd` which was **open by default**. I did not close it and so it was left open even after the move. This resulted in an open target and since I was just `lsof`ing on the target, I did not see that the tempfile was already opened. This would be the corrected version:

```
fd, temp_file_path = tempfile.mkstemp()
fd.write(content)
fd.close()

# ... mv/rename via shell execution/shutil/pathlib
```

Thank you all very much for your help and your suggestions!

Comment: File descriptors are identifiers of **open** files in a process. So it's not that "open by default", it's that it's simply impossible to obtain a file descriptor without opening the file. Moreover `mkstemp` is a function that calls the system call to safely create a temporary file and it creates the file and returns an open handle to it, otherwise a different process could delete it before your process can open it rendering the call "unsafe".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't able reproduce this behavior. I created a file `/tmp/tempfile` and ran a python script with the `subprocess.run` call you give followed by a long sleep. `/tmp/target` was not in use, nor did I see any unexpected open files in `lsof -p <pid>`.

(edit) I'm not surprised at this, because there's no way that your subprocess command is opening the file: `mv` does not open its arguments (you can check this with `ltrace`) and `subprocess.run` does not parse its argument or do anything with it besides pass it along to be `exec`-ed.

However, when I added some lines to open a file and write to it and then move that file, I see the same behavior you describe. This is the code:

```py
import subprocess
out=open('/tmp/tempfile', 'w')
out.write('hello')
subprocess.run(
    "mv /tmp/tempfile /tmp/target",
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
    universal_newlines=True,
    shell=True,
)
import time
time.sleep(5000)
```

In this case, the file is still open because it was never closed, and even though it's been renamed the original file handle still exists. My bet would be that you have something similar in your code that's creating this file and leaving open a handle to it.

Comment: to write the tmp file I do use `pathlib.Path(..).write_text()` this handles the file opening/closing well. see my edit when I check `lsof`. the whole file interaction is wrapped in a [npyscreen](https://npyscreen.readthedocs.io/) form. do you think that might causes the problem?

Comment: In your "before" lsof check you need to check `/tmp/tempfile`, not `/tmp/target`. The `mv` command edits the target directory, essentially, to rename the file, but doesn't affect any open handles. So if something has `/tmp/tempfile` open before the move, it will have `/tmp/target` open after the move.

Comment: I've added a paragraph about why the code you've shown can't be causing the problem you're seeing.

Comment: you were totally right! see edit. thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason why you don't use [shutil.move](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.move)? Otherwise it may be necassary to wait for the `mv` command to finish moving and then kill it, read stdin, run something like

```py
p = subprocess.run(...)
# wait to finish moving/read from stdin
p.terminate()
```

Of course `terminate` would be a bit harsh.

Edit: depending on your use `rsync`, which is not part of python, may be a elegant solution to keep your data synced over the network without writing a single line of code

Comment: yes, also tried shutil.move, same result. no network involved here. btw: subprocess.run: 'Run the command described by args. Wait for command to complete, then return a CompletedProcess instance.' so its blocking and afterwards the file is still open :(

Comment: what happens if you open the file with `file = open("/tmp/filename")` and close it immediately with `file.close()`?

Comment: Maybe you want to bind mount the file/folder? `sudo mount --bind /tmp/filename /tmp/target` or sym/hardlink it.

Comment: its the target file thats left open. no I dont want to bind mount it. still open, different file handler.

Answer (score 0):

you say it is still open by "mv" but you lsof result shown open by python. As it is an sub process see if the pid is the same of the python process maybe it is another python process.